# Nested Radical of Ramanujan

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, nested-radicals

I think I have sort of a proof of the following nested radical expression due to Ramanujan for $x\ge 0$.

> $$\large x+1=\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{1+(x+1)\sqrt{1+(x+2)\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}$$ for $ x\ge -1$

I just want to know if my proof is okay or there is a flaw, and if there is one I request to give some suggestions to eliminate them. Thank you. The proof is the following:

**Proof:** Let us define $$ a_n(x)=\underbrace{\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{1+(x+1)\sqrt{1+(x+2)\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}}_{n \ \mbox{terms}}$$ for $x\ge 0$ so that $$ a_1(x)=\sqrt{1+x},\ a_2(x)=\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{1+(x+1)}},\ a_3(x)=\cdots$$

---

and so on. Since $x\ge 0$ each one of the $a_n$ is defined (I am taking only the positive square root). Also, we note that $$a_{n+1}^2(x)=1+xa_{n}(x+1)$$

Now, we note that $\{a_n(x)\}$ is an increasing sequence and that $$a_n(x)<x+1$$ $\forall n\ge 1$, this is easy to prove by induction as below:

For $n=1$, $a_1(x)=\sqrt{1+x}<1+x$ since $x\ge 0\Rightarrow 1+x\ge 1$. SO it is true for $n=1$. Similarly, the truth can be proved for $n>1$.

Then $a_n(x)$ converges to $$l(x)=\sup_{n}a_n(x)\le x+1$$ Now I make the following claim:

**Claim:** *$l(x)=x+1\quad \forall i\ge 0$*

*Proof:* Fix $x$. Let $l(x)<x+1$. Then, $l(x)=x+1-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Now, I claim that there must be a $n$ such that $$x+1-a_n(x)<\epsilon$$, and if that is true then $$a_n(x)>x+1-\epsilon=l(x)$$ which is a contradiction since $$l(x)=\sup_{n}a_n(x)$$ and then it implies that $$l(x)=x+1$$ To prove my claim it requires $$x+1-a_n(x) <  \epsilon$$ Now, \begin{align}
x+1-a_n(x) = & x+1-\sqrt{1+xa_{n-1}(x+1)} \\
\ =& \frac{(x+1)^2-({1+xa_{n-1}(x+1)})}{x+1+\sqrt{1+xa_{n-1}(x+1)} } \\
\ =& x\frac{(x+1)+1-a_{n-1}(x+1)}{x+1+\sqrt{1+xa_{n-1}(x+1)} } \\
\ <& \frac{x}{x+2}((x+1)+1-a_{n-1}(x+1))\\
\ <& \frac{x}{x+2}\cdot\frac{x+1}{x+3}((x+2)+1-a_{n-2}(x+2))\\
\ <& \frac{x}{x+n-1}\cdot \frac{x+1}{x+n} ((x+n-1)+1-a_{1}(x+n-1))\\
\ <& \frac{x}{x+n-1}\cdot \frac{x+1}{x+n}(x+n-\sqrt{x+n})\\
\ <& \frac{x(x+1)}{x+n-1}
\end{align}

Now, if one is able to find $n$ such that $$\frac{x(x+1)}{x+n-1}<\epsilon
\Rightarrow x< \frac{-(1-\epsilon)+\sqrt{(1-\epsilon)^2+4\epsilon(n-1)}}{2}$$ then we're done.

Now from the upper bound it seems that there always exists some $n$ that satisfies this requirement. Hence the claim is proved.

Comment: Is it obvious that $a_n(i)<x+i+1$?

Comment: It seems like you'd just want to define $a_n(x)=\dots$ and note that $a_n(x)^2 = 1+xa_{n-1}(x+1)$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, actually by induction we can show that $a_n(i)<x+i+1$. And $a_n(x)$, is a function of $x$ but I want to define $a_n(i)$, **not** varying with $x$, in the way I have defined so that I can use them in the proof.

Comment: Yes, but your $a_n(i)$ are just my $a_n(x+i)$. And the recursions and most of the results are independent of $i$ and cleaner with just $x$. For example, $a_n(x)<x+1$ is cleaner than $a_n(i)<x+i+1$.  I think your use of $i$ actually makes it harder to follow some parts of the proof.

Comment: That is true, but the thing is I have defined them in that way to use them to get the last inequality. Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Ok, I understood your reasoning, its simpler. I'll modify it as u advised.

Comment: $a_n(x)<x+1$ has not been proven. It's not enough to say that $1+x>1$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Ok @Jonathan I'll include that proof in my answer.

Comment: You've written a lot of extra verbiage about $\sup$ in your proof, when all you really are doing is showing that $1+x-a_n(x)\to 0$, so $a_n(x)\to 1+x$. I think you have an off-by-one error at the end - it is $\frac{x(x+1)}{(x+n)(x+n-1)}(x+n-1-\sqrt{x+n-1})$, I think, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variant of your proof, for some clarity.

Define $a_1(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$ and $a_{n+1}(x)=\sqrt{1+xa_n(x+1)}$.

Define $b_n(x)=1+x-a_n(x)$. By your proof, we know that $b_n(x)$ is decreasing and bounded below by zero. You want to show that $b_n(x)\to 0$, and then you are done.

Now (this is pretty much exactly your proof, but it is made clearer by have $b_n$ defined): 
$$\begin{align}b_{n+1}(x) &= 1+x - a_{n+1}(x) 
\\&=\frac{(1+x)^2-a_{n+1}(x)^2}{1+x+a_{n+1}(x)}
\\&=\frac{1+2x+x^2-(1+xa_n(x+1))}{1+x+a_{n+1}(x)}
\\&= \frac{xb_n(x+1)}{1+x+a_{n+1}(x)}
\\&\leq\frac{x}{2+x}b_{n}(x+1)
\end{align}$$

By induction (for $n>k\geq 1$) you can show that:

$$b_n(x) \leq \frac{x(x+1)}{(x+k)(x+k+1)}b_{n-k}(x+k)$$

Therefore, for $k=n-1$, we get:

$$0\leq b_n(x)\leq \frac{x(x+1)}{(x+n-1)(x+n)}b_1(x+n-1) \leq \frac{x(x+1)}{x+n}$$

Therefore, $b_n(x)\to 0$, and hence $a_n(x)\to x+1$.

Comment: I've posted the one flaw in a comment above - you had an off-by-one error in the final case of the expansion (what in my proof is $k=n-1$.) But the real flaw is all the extra stuff about $\sup a_n(x)$ and $\epsilon$. It's not a logical flaw, it's just completely unnecessary. You just need to show that $x+1-a_n(x)\to 0$, and that is what you proved.

Comment: Yes, I agree with both the points, thanks!

Comment: The definition of $b_n$ lets me write $b_{n+1}(x)\leq \frac{x}{x+2}b_n(x+1)$, and that makes the reduction to $b_1$ much clearer, making me less likely to get an off-by-one error.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion regarding how to extend the proof to the case where $x\in \mathbb{R}$. All my proof (as well as yours I guess) hinges on the assumption $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Presumably, you mean $x\geq -1$? It's not clear what we'd mean with $x<-1$.

Comment: Initially I thought my proof holds for $x\geq -1$, but then I saw, it is not, it requires $x \geq 0$. And note that $a_n(x)$ is defined for $x\geq -(n-1)$, so I guess, as $n\rightarrow \infty$ $x\in \mathbb{R}$ should satisfy the identity of Ramanujan.

Comment: For $-1\leq x<0$, we that $a_n(x)=\sqrt{1+xa_{n-1}(x+1)}$. Letting $n\to\infty$ on both sides, you get $a_n(x)\to \sqrt{1+x(x+2)} = 1+x$.

Comment: Correct! So I can just use this equation recursively to extend my proof for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: Well, when $2\leq x<-1$,  $\sqrt{1+2x+x^2}$ becomes $|1+x|=-1-x$, and then you can't proceed by induction in general.

Comment: Yes, I see, the identity is not true for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, because for $x=-3$, the RHS gives $\sqrt{-2}$, whereas the LHS gives $-2$. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

$x>-1\iff \underline{x+1}=\sqrt{(x+1)^2}=\sqrt{1+2x+x^2}=\sqrt{1+x\cdot(\underline{\underline{x+2}})}$

$\begin{align}x>-2\iff \underline{\underline{x+2}}=\sqrt{(x+2)^2}=\sqrt{[(x+1)+1]^2}&=\sqrt{1+2(x+1)+(x+1)^2}=\\&=\sqrt{1+(x+1)(\underline{\underline{\underline{x+3}}})}\end{align}$

$\to x+1=\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{1+(x+1)(\underline{\underline{x+3}})}}\quad-\quad$ Can you see where this is going ? :-)

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thanks.