# Inequality concerning a function :${(f(x))}^2=1+xf(x+1)$

Tags: functions, inequality, contest-math, functional-equations

> If $f:[0,\infty]\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is such that for all $x\in [0,\infty]$ :$${(f(x))}^2=1+xf(x+1)$$  Prove that for all $x\ge 1$ $$\frac{x+1}{2}\le f(x)\le  2(x+1)$$

First of all I have never had experience proving such inequalities and since nothing is said about the differentiability I don't know whether calculus would be a good approach. We can however draw the following conclusions for all $x\ge 1$

- As $f(x)\ge 1$ we have $$f(x)^2=1+xf(x+1)\ge 1+x \implies f(x)\ge \sqrt{x+1}$$
- By Bernoulli's inequality $$f(x)=\sqrt{1+xf(x+1)}\le 1+\frac{xf(x+1)}{2}$$
- As $f(x+1)\le f^2(x+1)$ and $x\le x^2$ $$f(x)^2=1+xf(x+1)\le 1+x^2f^2(x+1)$$  $$(f(x)-xf(x+1))(f(x)+xf(x+1))\le 1$$

That's it, I couldn't get any more ideas ...

P.S. The problem is from [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h2416405_weird_fe).

Comment: $f(x)=\sqrt{1+xf(x+1)}\ge 1+\frac{xf(x+1)}{2}\ge1+\frac{x\sqrt{x+1}}{2}$ and you can easily prove it is superior to $\frac{x+1}{2}$.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea i think it is not assumed that it can be derived, it is?]

Comment: Say $f(0.1) = 10$, then $f(1.1) = 990$, and each of $f(n+0.1)$ would be greater than $0$, but $f(x)$ would be greater than $2(x+1)$. Maybe if $f$ is continuous, the inequality as stated would be true?

Comment: @math: Unless I am mistaken, your estimate is wrong. Note that $\sqrt{1+a} \le 1 +a/2$ for all $a \ge 0$.

Comment: @MartinR thanks it was a typo so proof of lower bound is gone!

Comment: @math my application of bernoullis inequality was wrong ;(

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/q/458740 proves that $f(x) \ge 1+x$.

Comment: @MartinR nice find! as $1+x\ge \frac{1+x}{2}$ we are done for the lower bound,Do you have any ideas to approach to prove the upper bound

Comment: @MartinR ok,  anyway thanks for fishing that post up

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for pointing out, I delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A stronger lower bound

Define the functions $a_n: [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ recursively as
$$
\begin{align}
 a_0(x) &= 1 \, ,\\
 a_{n+1}(x) &= \sqrt{1+xa_n(x+1)} \, .
\end{align}
$$
In [Nested Radical of Ramanujan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458740/nested-radical-of-ramanujan) it is shown that for all $x \ge 0$
$$
 \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n(x) = x+1 \, .
$$
On the other hand, $f(x) \ge a_n(x)$ follows from the given functional equation with induction. Therefore
$$
 f(x) \ge x + 1 \text{ for all } x \ge 0.
$$

#### There is no upper bound

Choose an arbitrary function $g:[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ with $g(0) = 1$ and $g(x) \ge 1+x$. Define $f$ on $[0, 1]$ as $f(x) = g(x)$, and extend the definition to all intervals $(n, n+1]$, $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, with
$$
 f(x) = \frac{f(x-1)^2 - 1}{x-1} \, .
$$
Note that $f(x-1) \ge x$ on $(n-1, n]$ implies that $f(x) \ge x+1$ on $(n, n+1]$, so that $f$ is well-defined for all $x \ge 0$ and satisfies the functional equation.

But $f(1) = g(1)$ can be arbitrarily large.

*Remark:* If $g$ is chosen as a differentiable function with $g(1) = 2g(0)g'(0)$ then $f$ is continuous at $x=1$ and therefore continuous everywhere. An example would be $g(x) = 1+kx + (k-1)x^2$ for any $k \ge 1$.

Comment: I see thanks! ,there might be some glitch in the question..(will accept the answer by today)